# Blog menu and content changes showing up and dissapearing

Tags: mysql, wordpress, caching

I'm having an issue with my Wordpress install after making changes to a page or a menu the changes appear briefly and then disappear, after making the same change multiple times (with minor differences) after every couple of refreshes the site alternates between different alternates of the edit. So for example:

If I add a new menu item it will stay there for three minutes after which if I refresh it will disappear, then if I add a different menu item again it will also stay for about thee minutes and disappear again only to be replaced by the menu item that had disappeared three minutes ago.

Here are some of the things I have tried to resolve the issue:
1. Turned on debugging, identified one minor error to do with the database and fixed it.
2. Turned off all the plugins, still had the same issue.
3. Emptying all of my own browser caches and & restarting the computer; the issue persisted.
4. Installing w3 cache and emptying all caches
5. I have contacted my server admin and he says we are not running a cache on the webserver
6. I Hav elaso tried using the theme on a clean install with several updates etc .. but the issue didn't happen there, so its not the theme

Any idea what this may be? or how to fix it?

I was thinking this may be an issue with the database ...

Additionally any changes made to the theme etc using FTP do not have the same issue...

Comment: Try disabling unnecessay plugins

Comment: i did it didn't help